# How to Insert date from JFormatedTextField with mask

Tags: java, sql-server, date, jformattedtextfield

I am working on a app there are some JFormatedTextFields with mask formatted (##/##/#### as dd/MM/YYYY). I am trying to insert these date into Database but it is showing an error "Error Converting data type nvarchar to Date"
[Error Converting data type nvarchar to Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJjnf.jpg)

but I could not find any problem in my sql procedure because if I run that procedure using sql query analyzer it is working but if I try to execute from app it is showing error

here is my all codes

sql procedure

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Proc_set_ExamDeclaration]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure [dbo].[Proc_set_ExamDeclaration]
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO


CREATE  Procedure [dbo].[Proc_set_ExamDeclaration]
                     (
                    @SchoolCode nvarchar (10),
                    @ClassCode nvarchar (4),
                    @GroupName nvarchar(50),
                    @ExamCode nvarchar (4),
                    @RegistationFess numeric(38,2),
                    @RegistatinStartDate date,
                    @RegistatinEndDate date,
                    @ExamStartDate date,
                    @ExamStatus nvarchar(10)
                    )
as

BEGIN
-- Insert statements for procedure here
Declare @RFirst as Date, @REnd as Date, @EStart as Date
set @RFirst = CONVERT(varchar, @RegistatinStartDate, 103)
set @REnd = CONVERT(varchar, @RegistatinEndDate, 103)
set @EStart = CONVERT(varchar, @ExamStartDate, 103)
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ExamDeclaration] where ClassCode = @ClassCode AND GroupName = @GroupName AND ExamCode = @ExamCode AND ExamStatus = 'Active')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ExamDeclaration (SchoolCode, ClassCode,GroupName,ExamCode,RegistationFess,RegistatinStartDate,RegistatinEndDate,ExamStartDate,ExamStatus)
VALUES (@SchoolCode, @ClassCode,@GroupName,@ExamCode,@RegistationFess,@RFirst,@REnd,@EStart,@ExamStatus)
END
ELSE 
Update ExamDeclaration 
set RegistationFess = @RegistationFess,
RegistatinStartDate = @RFirst,
RegistatinEndDate = @REnd,
ExamStartDate = @EStart,
ExamStatus = @ExamStatus
Where ClassCode = @ClassCode AND GroupName=@GroupName AND ExamCode = @ExamCode
END

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

and here is the java codes

```
    String School_Code = txt_SchoolCode.getText();
    String ClassCode = txt_ClassCode.getText();
    String groupName = com_groupname.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String examCode = txt_ExamCode.getText();
    String fees = txt_fees.getText();        
    String RStart = txt_RStart.getText();//((JTextField) txt_RStart.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String REnd = txt_REnd.getText();//((JTextField) txt_REnd.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String EStart = txt_ExamStart.getText();//((JTextField) txt_ExamStart.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();        
    String Estatus = com_eStatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(ClassCode.isEmpty() && examCode.isEmpty() && fees.isEmpty() /*&& RStart.isEmpty() && REnd.isEmpty() && EStart.isEmpty()*/){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All Fields are Required !!");}
    else{
        try{
            String sqlExamD = "Exec Proc_set_ExamDeclaration ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sqlExamD);
            pst.setString(1, School_Code);
            pst.setString(2, ClassCode);
            pst.setString(3, groupName);
            pst.setString(4, examCode);
            pst.setString(5, fees);
            pst.setString(6, RStart);
            pst.setString(7, REnd);
            pst.setString(8, EStart);
            pst.setString(9, Estatus);

            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved Successfuly");
            btn_new.doClick();

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

any Idea where is the problem in my codes?

I am using java netbeans and sql server 2008

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you have you assign your date variables in Java as strings, but you have them actually defined as dates:

```
String RStart = txt_RStart.getText();
...
@RegistatinStartDate date
```

And then you try to convert from date to varchar but assign it back to a date?

```
Declare @RFirst as Date
...
set @RFirst = CONVERT(varchar, @RegistatinStartDate, 103)
```